# Is there something like a static thread_local method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I guess it would not make much sense and I'm not sure what a `static thread_local` method would do, but does this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` unfortunately in C++ has many different unrelated meanings.

`thread_local` is a storage class specifier, and can be combined with `static` (that can also be used as a storage class specifier).

`static` in a method declaration however is NOT a storage class specifier and therefore talking about `thread_local` in this context is nonsense.

In C++ methods are not data: they don't have a lifetime and they take no storage.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is clear on this: thread_local is implicitly static.

You can write static thread_local if you want clarity, but be assured that it is exactly equivalent to thread_local.